# libgdx tutorial missing atlas file

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to use the tutorial code found at https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/ as a starting point for my first libgdx app.  While the code is still available on github, the assets were stored elsewhere and the link is dead  (https://stormyvids.is-sweet.co.uk/download.php?id=$1$jbN3SEQd$TAARaJXfzq6N/bDMeLHAQ1).

Does anyone have the referenced images/loading.atlas file (+others?)?  I understand that snapshots of the internet exist, would one of them have this file from 3 years ago?

If not that, perhaps a link to another code repository where a beginner can see how experts use libgdx?

Comment: Are you already familiar with object oriented programming? I learned LibGDX initially by browsing the code of open source projects. If you look for LibGDX game jams, you can find the source code for many small projects. You can look to the higher rated games as being more likely to be following good practices (although that's not going to correlate perfectly, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I didn't know about game jams before.  Yes, I'm familiar with OOP.

Comment: The first jam had the most submissions, because there was a prize. https://itch.io/jam/libgdxjam